# One Model field not populating when the rest of the Model is

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using an MVC 3 view which has a Model inherited:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>"
```

I use html helpers to populate model properties:

```
<td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(i => Model.partA, new { @style = "width:25px;", @maxLength = 3})%></td>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(t => Model.partB, new { @style = "width:35px;", @maxLength = 5 })%></td>
```

The problem is in my controller 'partB' gets the value from my TextBoxFor helper but 'partA' is empty.  There's other parts of the model but I use this as an example.

It's the same model based on the same table in my entity framework.  I checked the properties and they're both intergers with Nullable set to (none).  In SQl Server MS, the table fields it's refering to appear to be the same also.  Both are set (int, null).

I don't see what the difference is that causes partB to be populated and partA to be empty.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was because I had a textbox also named 'partA' in a control being rendered in my page.  The empty value in the control seemed to be overwriting 'partA' on my view.